# Resample doesn't recognize my index as datetime

Tags: datetime, pandas

I am using a datetime.date field as my index and it doesn't seem to agree that it is datetime for some reason.

First I will verity that the field is indeed datetime.date format:

```
In [1]: df[date][0]

Out [1]: datetime.date(2010, 1, 1)
```

Now I try to resample by week and plot the mean:

```
In [2]: df.set_index(date)[var].resample('W', how='mean').plot()

/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc in resample(self, rule, how, axis, fill_method, closed, label, convention, kind, loffset, limit, base)
   2878                               fill_method=fill_method,    convention=convention,
   2879                               limit=limit, base=base)
-> 2880         return sampler.resample(self).__finalize__(self)
   2881 
   2882     def first(self, offset):

/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tseries/resample.pyc in resample(self, obj)
    100             return self.obj
    101         else:  # pragma: no cover
--> 102             raise TypeError('Only valid with DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex')
    103 
    104         rs_axis = rs._get_axis(self.axis)

TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex
```

I can't provide sample data because it's proprietary.  Any thoughts on what might be going on here?

Comment: just to check does `df1 = df.set_index(date)  df1[var].resample('W', how='mean').plot()` work?

Comment: Can you try explicitly converting to a datetime index so your code would look like:`df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(date))[var].resample('W', how='mean').plot()`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to convert the date column to a pandas time series first. 
Try:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df.set_index('date')[var]....
```

I've been told by Pandas dev that `datetime` objects in pandas indices are inefficient are to be avoided where possible.

Comment: I execute this earlier in the code when I import the data.  Let me try to convert a second time to see if that clears it up.  Give me a few minutes.